# trim the output on command line unix

Tags: linux, bash

I have an ouput from the command line, i need to trim and get the desired output as shown below:

Input:

```
['0x66']
['0x66', '0x137', '0xa9']
[]
['0x148', '0x11a', '0x167', '0x151', '0xe6']
[]
['0x171', '0xe2', '0x174']
```

Output:

```
0x66
0x66
0x137
0xa9
0x148
0x11a
0x151
0xe6
```

I used: **tr -d "[]',"** but after removing those do linux has any command like .split() in python.

**[EDIT] After looking at the man pages of tr, I see there is a translate option so I piped the whole ouptut to:**

```
output | tr -d "[]' | tr " " "\n"
```

Comment: Looks like it is JSON (or smth. like that) and it should be parsed instead of being string-manipulated.

Comment: @Roman, ...if it were JSON, it'd be double rather than single quotes.

Comment: ...if it *were* JSON, then `jq -r '.[]'` would do the trick.

Comment: it isn't JSON, it's a grep output

Answer (score 4):

I suggest using simple `grep -o` (show only matching text):

```
grep -o "0x[^']*" file

0x66
0x66
0x137
0xa9
0x148
0x11a
0x167
0x151
0xe6
0x171
0xe2
0x174
```

Comment: @Snort5121: If output shown in `grep` output then you can pipe to `| grep -o "0x[^']*"`

Answer (score 0):

How about piping to this:

```
| tr -d "[]' " | tr ',' '\n' | sed -n '/^.\+$/p'
```

It first deletes useless chars, then "splits" the fields to their own lines and then removes any empty ones.

Answer (score 0):

With `tr` and a little help from `sed`:

```
tr -d "[]' " <file.txt | sed -n '/./ p' | tr ',' '\n'
```

- `tr -d "[]' " removes all`[`,`]`, space and single quotes from the data
- `sed` part matches lines with at least one character to leave out empty lines
- Then `tr ',' '\n'` converts all commas to newlines

---

```
% cat file.txt
['0x66']
['0x66', '0x137', '0xa9']
[]
['0x148', '0x11a', '0x167', '0x151', '0xe6']
[]
['0x171', '0xe2', '0x174']

% tr -d "[]' " <file.txt | sed -n '/./ p' | tr ',' '\n'       
0x66
0x66
0x137
0xa9
0x148
0x11a
0x167
0x151
0xe6
0x171
0xe2
0x174
```